# load 20 images in a page from a php file that loads all images within the same directory

Tags: php, html

I have 100+ image in one directory and I use the following php code to generate a page that displays the latest pictures on top.

```
<?php
function mtimecmp($a, $b) {
    $mt_a = filemtime($a);
    $mt_b = filemtime($b);

    if ($mt_a == $mt_b)
        return 0;
    else if ($mt_a < $mt_b)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
usort($images, "mtimecmp");

for ($i = count($images) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $image = $images[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" height ="400"/><br />';
}
```

?>

What I want to do is generate a new page (either in html or php) that displays the last 20 pages, then give a user an option to load more images. This way when they visit the page they don't have to load all 100+ pictures but just 20.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are either looking for pagination or AJAX requests! Google those

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking, anything that involves modifying the page after load is done with something other than php.  I use javascript, and for what you're trying to do, I would use JQuery.  With JQuery, it would look something like this

```
<a id='load_twenty_button'>Load 20 more!</a>
<div id='where_to_put_the_images'></div>

<script>
   var img_start = 20;

   //when link is clicked, do the function
   $('#load_twenty_button').click( function() {
       var link = 'my_site/form_actions/getImages.php'
       $.post(link
        , {   start: img_start
            , end: img_start +20
          }
        , function (result) 
          { 
              //set the html of the div element to the html your php link return
              $('#where_to_put_the_images').html(result);  
              img_start += 20;
          }   
        );
    });
</script>
```

Then for your getIMages.php, use $_POST['start'] and $_POST['end'] to figure out which images to echo in html.  Anything echo'd will be posted to the div element 'where_to_put_images'.  You're going to have to work it a tiny bit if you want to add twenty more after that, but this should get you there.

Also, make sure to link the JQuery.  Just look up a basic JQuery example, it'll be linked in the top.

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy thought, just only take my code as a refrence, you can use `array_slice` function here

```
<?php
  function mtimecmp( $a, $b ) {
    $mt_a = filemtime( $a );
    $mt_b = filemtime( $b );

    if ( $mt_a == $mt_b ) {
      return 0;
    }
    elseif ( $mt_a < $mt_b ) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  }

  $images = glob( $dirname."*.jpg" );
  usort( $images, "mtimecmp" );

  $page   = ( isset( $_GET["page"] ) ) ? $_GET["page"] : 1; // current page
  $offset = ( $page * 20 ); // array_slice offset
  $length = 20; // maximum images per page
  $images = array_slice( $images, -$offset, $length ); // slice images array

  if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
    foreach( $images as $image ) {
      echo '<img src="'.$image.'" height="400" /> ';
    }
  }
?>
```

and for the pagination, html will looks like something like this, its really simple method

```
<div>
  <a href="?page=<?php echo ( $page - 1 ); ?>">Prev</a>
  <a href="?page=<?php echo ( $page + 1 ); ?>">Next</a>
</div>
```